# Right way to index photos with different formats on website

Tags: seo, google-search-console, sitemap, images, google-index

I am working on a website with a lot of pro photos. So I've decided to create 4 different formats for each photo:

`*_sm.jpg` - thumbnail

when you click on a photo you will get a bigger photo in the special gallery:

`*.jpg` - 1920 (width) for desktop version.

`*_mobile.jpg` - 1000 (width) for mobile website.
+ in the gallery there will be a link to the page with original photo 6000x4000.

By this method I have **4 formats** and the user can open the source photo if he needs it.

Should I create a sitemap for images? Which of those have I to include there and which is better to block for index (in htaccess for example).

Comment: are you selling these photos or are they free to download?

Comment: @AbuNooh they are free, thumbnail doesn't have watermark, other format s - does.

Comment: For maximum exposure in image search I would have thought you'd want _all_ 4 sizes indexed, since users can specify the required size in search. (?)

Comment: @w3d so, logically, I shoud set canonical / alternate urls, to show the main photo and other formats, but I cannot find if it is supported

Comment: Hhhmm, not canonical. And I'm not sure how you'd _explicitly_ specify "alternate" image URLs? Other than naturally linking to them in your source. (Google is able to determine if images are _similar_.) Personally, I would just make sure they are all _linked to_ and include them in your image sitemap, as Josip suggests.

Comment: @w3d thank you! I decided to add all of them to sitemap and I noticed that I can set a caption for each photo, but my website is miltilanguage... So if I ignore the caption, should google find its caption from alt attribute on the website... Oh, it's so difficult to understand the right way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Google image extensions for sitemaps to give Google more information about the images available on your pages. Image sitemap information helps Google discover images that we might not otherwise find (such as images your site reaches with JavaScript code), and allows you to indicate images on your site that you want Google to crawl and index.

You can use a separate sitemap to list images, or you can add image information to an existing sitemap.

Comment: Is there a way to set alternate images (the same one in different format) or I have just to include all of them and that's it..?